# Sistema sempre retorna status 500

Tags: wordpress, mamp, localhost

Tenho uma aplicação wordpress que está rodando em produção, e com código versionado.
Estou tentando montar o ambiente de desenvolvimento em um Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, para tanto, fiz as mesmas configurações do ambiente ubuntu, também de desenvolvimento. Contudo, quando tento acessar o site, tenho 500 para qualquer página do wordpress que tento acessar.

O estranho é que se eu iniciar um projeto do 0 funciona normalmente.

A configuração feita no ambiente ubuntu é a especificada [aqui](http://tutsmais.com.br/blog/wordpress/como-migrar-uma-aplicacao-wordpress-de-um-servidor-para-outro/), seguindo este tutorial consegui rodar. Essa mesma configuração foi feita no mac, usando MAMP.

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer rodar no mac?

Comment: Veja a sessão [página em branco](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema.

Passei a usar o XAMPP.

Por algum motivo, que soube identificar, o MAMP não conseguia renderizar minha aplicação.